# How can i update my screen correctly in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make my [own widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5cWi.png), that can resize itself by using sliders on the edges but when I quickly resize the widget, I see it not displaying correctly on the screen.
Look it:
[incorrect display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKimD.png)

I use place method for wigdet objects. --> When Frame resizes then its dots(Frame too) re-position relative to the Frame geometry by using place method. I don't know how to fix this mess(blur) on the screen. Pls answer me how to fix it and sorry for my english).

If you want to know if I tried the update and update_idletasks methods, then yes, but they didn’t help me, they don’t work the way I need, if they works then slow down all program.
Should I switch to pyqt5 because of this?

Part of code for change right width:

```
    def right():
        nonlocal screen_update
        width = cursor_x - self.x.indent
        'gets new width'

        parent_width = Core.get_geometry(self.parent.winfo_geometry())[0]
        "gets parent's width"

        if cursor_x > parent_width:
            width = parent_width - self.x.indent

        if width < w_min:
            width = w_min

        self['width'] = width
        screen_update = True
```

Part of code for change left width:

```
    def left():
        nonlocal screen_update, cursor_x
        width = self.x.size + self.x.indent - cursor_x
        "gets new self's width"

        if cursor_x < 0:
            cursor_x = 0
            width = self.x.size + self.x.indent

        if width < w_min:
            width = w_min
            cursor_x = self.x.size + self.x.indent - width

        self['width'] = width
        self.x.indent = cursor_x
        self.place(x=cursor_x, y=self.y.indent)
        screen_update = True
```

Then:

```
    self.get_geometry()  # write down self's geometry in x and y attributes
    self.place_dots()  # just place dots
```

place_dots():

```
def place_dots(self):
    """places all dots"""
    size = self.dot.left.size
    self.dot.left.place(x=self.x.indent - size//2, y=self.y.indent + self.y.size//2 - size//2)

    self.dot.right.place(x=self.x.indent + self.x.size - size//2, y=self.y.indent + self.y.size//2 - size//2)

    self.dot.up.place(x=self.x.indent + self.x.size//2 - size//2, y=self.y.indent - size//2)

    self.dot.down.place(x=self.x.indent + self.x.size//2 - size//2, y=self.y.indent + self.y.size - size//2)

    self.dot.right_up.place(x=self.x.indent + self.x.size - size//2, y=self.y.indent - size//2)

    self.dot.right_down.place(x=self.x.indent + self.x.size - size//2, y=self.y.indent + self.y.size - size//2)

    self.dot.left_up.place(x=self.x.indent - size//2, y=self.y.indent - size//2)

    self.dot.left_down.place(x=self.x.indent - size//2, y=self.y.indent + self.y.size - size//2)
```

Comment: could you please keep code.

Comment: @Dodu, already updated.

Comment: Look's like you forget to redraw on a an empty background. What I mean is on video games when you want to draw a new frame you will set the entire view port with one color and then draw new this on top of it. In an terminal game also is used this method by clearing all and then writing again. Is same concept but on other level. So try to delete everything and place dots and shapes again on a new background.

Comment: @ASI, if you mean use place_forget method then it doesn't work. Always redraw background maybe can help but my background contains a lot of small rectangle what can slow down future programm but I will test it. I think I understand how it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Black_ByProsti you have your point. But from your image is look like a common error when we forget to clear the screen before to draw a new frame. If is killing your performance then you can consider using multithreading if is possible.

Comment: @ASI, okay, how can I clear the screen in tkinter? I try anything but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Black_ByProsti Sorry for late answer, I was busy. From what I see on the image, is look like you are using **Tkinter** to create your widget. So I assume you are using **Canvas** to draw things on the screen, so in this case you can delete everything from a canvas using **delete** method like `canvas.delete("all")`, where "all" is a special tag for doing what is mean.

Comment: Also, PyQt5 is not free, requires you to purchase a commercial license. You can give a shot on Kivy, is also a cross platform and is under MIT license witch is basically free.

Comment: @ASI, yes I use tkinter for my programm because it is simpler. But I don't draw all widgets in canvas). I made transform widget that can move using place method but tkinter  can't display widgets and update new frame properly. Example I made another widget "Area" this widget uses scrolbars if it needed, and again, if you quickly move around the area, you will immediately see "screen blur". Area widget consists of main frame then canvas because this widget supports scrolbars, then frame as Window in canvas, then another frame_2 because in frame as Window you can't use place method, only pack

Comment: @ASI,  I already forgot about this problem because it isn't my fault and it makes me happy. I just don't pay attention to it, because I'm doing the program purely for myself. And I won't be able to programming for more than 2-3 weeks((

Comment: OK. If you reconsider to get back to this an alternative option is to use **pygame** because is more close to an OpenGL or even the **PyOpenGL** it self. I start to do same thing as you tried with pygame because my project will have just 2D graphics and also because python OpenGL is to heavy for my targeting hardware. Like an hint, with this two options you will need to do all GUI logic from beginning almost. You can give it a try. Another option for you is to use [ImGUI](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) which I allready test it with C++ and pygame. You can edit the source code to your needs.

Comment: @ASI, About pygame I learned before and this is great idea, but firstly I must to finish my own reference then learn new python library. Thank you very much for help. You realy helped me a lot.